# jquery keypress condition glitch any key

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am having a problem with jQuery. i am trying to create an even that is triggered by a single key pressed, but instead -some of it- is triggered by any key. don't understand why. i have done this a bunch of times and had no problem. all of a sudden this particular combination of code is acting weird. i don't understand. i have tried all sorts of experiments on it to figure it out. the problem is very specific and consistent on multiple browsers. please help! here is the link to the page. http://www.lyliansill.com/test.html>
to see what i am talking about press 'a' and it works like it should. reload and press any other keys and half of the event is still triggered.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C/DTD/ XHTML 1.0 Strict/EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtd/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<!-- This file is on level 02 -->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">

<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />

    <title>Test</title>

    <style type="text/css">
    .hidden
    {
        display: none;
    }
    .select
    {
        color:#cc0000;
    }

    </style> 

</head>

<body>

    <h1 class="test hidden">Test</h1>

<script type="text/javascript" src="playground/libraries/jquery.js">

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function showIt()
{
    $(".showIt").show();
}

$(document).keypress
(
    function(e)
    {
        if (e.which === 97)
        $(".test").addClass("select"); // this line works like it should

        $(".test").addClass("showIt"); // these two lines are activated... 
        showIt();                      // ...by pressing any key! why??
    }
);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You forgot the curly brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is why you should make sure to use brackets, lets look at the code:

```
if (e.which === 97)
$(".test").addClass("select"); // this line works like it should

$(".test").addClass("showIt"); // these two lines are activated... 
showIt();                      // ...by pressing any key! why??
```

Notice the if statements has no brackets: `if(){ ... }`, so the line under is is only executed if that if-statement is true, but the rest is not in the if statement so:

```
$(".test").addClass("showIt"); // these two lines are activated... 
showIt();                      // ...by pressing any key! why??
```

Always runs. To fix this add brackets:

```
if (e.which === 97) {
    $(".test").addClass("select"); // this line works like it should
    $(".test").addClass("showIt"); // these two lines are activated... 
    showIt();                      // ...by pressing any key! why??
}
```

Comment: Don't worry, we have all made errors like these before (definitely if you been programming in Python), it in no ways means your stupid. Very smart people make errors like this quite often, then feel silly.

Answer (score 0):

here's how to fix it (Add curly braces):

`function(e)
    {
        if (e.which === 97) {
          $(".test").addClass("select"); // this line works like it should`

```
      $(".test").addClass("showIt"); // these two lines are activated... 
      showIt();
    }                      // ...by pressing any key! why??
}
```